# Admin IsAn Employee relationship not suitable for inheritance?

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism, uml, diagram, class-diagram

I have this scenario to be modeled by a UML class diagram and I do not concur with the comment in bold.

> *Courses* can belong to *categories* and each category has assigned its own *administrator*, which is also an *employee* (can be changed,
>   therefor **not appropriate to be solved by inheritance**).

Why is Employee <|== Administrator not suitable for inheritance? I think it clearly is a "is a" relationship, not "has a". The thing that they can "switch" can easily be solved by casting on both sides. The extra attributes would be dropped, the missing ones would be initialized to NULL or some default value.

Comment: What does "can be changed" mean? What is going to be changed? I think that statement is ambiguous.

Comment: @ThomasKilian It means the Administrator can become an Employee (be demoted) and vice versa (be promoted).

Answer (score 1):

While this is not clearly stated, but part

> not appropriate to be solved by inheritance

gives you a hint how to understand

> can be changed

The important part that *could be* inheritance if there was no bracket part comes from this part

> administrator, which is also an employee

Yet, you have information that this can be changed (e.g. there might be an external administrator in the future or administration part can be excluded to a separate company so the administrator will no longer be an employee). Thus you cannot take the fact that administrator is an employee (in future it might no longer be true even thoe it is now) and so you can't use inheritance to model this relationship.

Comment: Still a lot of reading the tea leaves. I'd ask the author of the OP's citation what he actually meant. One can't design based on speculation.

Comment: @Ister Thats clever explanation, even though it just ment "to be demoted from employee Admin to employee Employee". I can see the problem you demonstrated, but consider now the intended meaning. The author of the citation claims, the problem is the object would have to be casted. I disagree, why is it a problem? The author sugests association instead of inheritance, but again, its a "IsA" relationship. It might work, but semantically it just does not feel right.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this model (I merged two models in one here):

[image]

What is the difference between the left and the right admin? The left has all the attributes and operations of `Employee` inherited, making them accessible to `Category`. But that should only be able to interact with the `Admin` part. In the right version, `Admin` can make it's `Employee`-relation private and thus it's not accessible for `Category`.

The pro-/demote in any case needs to be handled by removing it from `Category`. So what about runtime? When you deal with `Admin` that has inherited, you would just use that object in all operations where `Employee` is needed. Now, when he's no longer an admin, what has to be done? You have to create a simple `Employee` and give him those parts needed from the former `Admin`.

[image]

In the right case, you just delete the `Admin`.

[image]